# How do I make an erasing animation in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a webpage designed in CSS and HTML that shows stuff written on a blackboard.

When the user clicks on a link on the homepage, I want the user to see a huge hand with a duster act like erasing the content to reveal the new webpage.

Is it possible to achieve this animation using only CSS? If not, then how do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can try to do it with [CSS3 @keyframes rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) by using some image of huge hand with a duster moving from one side to another and erasing the content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer.  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not abuse the answer system. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!